# Typescript - typing array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I am having trouble typing array methods

```
 const person = students.findIndex((student) => student.id === 23)
```

The first error I get is on student element in the brackets

```
 const person = students.findIndex((student) => student.id === 23)
```

TS7006: Parameter 'student' implicitly has an 'any' type.

This can be fixed by

```
 const person = students.findIndex((student:any) => student.id === 23)
```

Which is not great so I try

```
 const person = students.findIndex((student:Object) => student.id === 23)
```

but I get

**TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'**

I assume because Object is a generic Type.

What is best practice here? I do hundreds of these with **filter, map, reduce** do I have to define the element being processed by the method in typesscript?

Comment: Does your `students` array have a type?

Comment: Create interface `Student` which you stores in students array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Student` interface and provide the same in place of `Object` and any other places for type check. I recommend to mention type explicitly(good coding practice) even though TS can do implicit type check.

```
interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // other properties...
}

const students: Student[] = [{
  id: 123,
  name: "test123"
},
{
  id: 456,
  name: "test456"
}]; // Suppose this is the data example

const person = students.findIndex((student: Student) => student.id === 23)
```

Comment: Although this works, syntactically.. This is incorrect semantically. Interface in Object Oriented programming works for declaring a list of abstract methods that a class is supposed to implement. In this case `Student` is not a class. So it is semantically incorrect to use interface. Which is why TS has introduced a concept of types

Comment: How do you know `Student` is not a class which is not mentioned in above question. Even you supposed it's a `Type`, and which is not correct to assume sth. Usually this will be class in most scenarios as student is an object.

Comment: Yep, which is exactly why it has to be assumed to be a Type. An `Object` in JS is not to be confused with the OO object.

Comment: Don't relate it with OO object, We have class and interface features in JS. So Student `interface` describes the data attributes and can be extended by other `interface` etc.

Comment: Like I said before, there are no methods that will be implemented inside your interface. It only lists property names for the object. Which is not what interface is used for... JS has no notion of interface, which gives is extreme dynamic abilities, as well as lot of headache if you use the duck typing incorrectly. TS interface and types are designed just to solve these problems. For the same of simplicity, if you interface has no methods, use type

Comment: I know about the differences b/w type and interface, but you  are talking about based on assumption without knowing all context details which is not mentioned in question. As mentioned in your  comment `it has to be assumed`. So I'd say you shouldn't conclude based on assumptions, that it's right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use TypeScript's implicit typing.

Create a type

```
type Student = {
  name: string;
};

const students: Student[] = [
  { name: 'ABC' },
  { name: 'DEF' }
];

const person = students.findIndex( student => student.name === 'ABC' ); // 0
```

When you declare your `students` variable as an array of `Student` type, your array prototype will extend itself to include Student types. So your array prototype methods will consider Student as their type as long as you call those methods on the students array.